# Como encontrar e mostrar a posição de um item na lista, não definindo o valor da string para a busca?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Como encontrar e mostrar a posição de um item na lista, não definindo o valor da string para a busca?

*Ex:*

```
nome_pessoa = str(input('Informe o seu nome completo: '))

lista_nomes = nome_pessoa.split()
```

Após os nomes serem divididos e transformados em lista, gostaria de saber como por exemplo, informar qual a posição o terceiro nome(ou item) se encontra.

Suponhamos que nessa primeira execução, o usuário tenha digitado o nome : 'Pedro Lucas Gomes'.

Dessa maneira, após transformar essa string na lista com os nomes, ela irá possuir os itens: **['Pedro', 'Lucas', 'Gomes']**

O que eu quero na ***saída*** de dados, ou seja, *printado* na tela é:

O nome da segunda posição, que nesse caso seria 'Gomes', e o número da posição, que será 2.

MAS CASO NA SEGUNDA EXECUÇÃO, o usuário digite o nome 'João Neves Frufru Feitosa', o que eu quero na saída é:

O nome da segunda posição, é 'Frufru', e o número da sua posição, é 2.

Conseguiram entender?
Eu não vou utilizar o comando:

print(lista_nomes.index('Frufru'))

Porque o nome 'Frufru', não será fixo no código! O nome pedido no programa, será digitado a partir do teclado pelo usuário no momento de cada execução do código.

(Agradeço à todos que estão se esforçando para ajudar e peço perdão pela minha falta de clareza antes da edição)

Answer (score 0):

Use "index" para pegar a posição do item na lista.

```
lista_nomes.index('Gomes')
```

Não sei se é isso que você quer, mas esta é a forma padrão de se pegar um endereço em uma lista.

Comment: Agradeço muito pela resposta meu caro, mas não é o que quero, porém, foi quase. 

O que quero na saída de dados é mostrar o nome de determinada posição, e o número da posição desse item. 

Ex: Se o nome da pessoa for 'João Mota Silva Mufino', o nome da terceira posição que será mostrado no terminal, vai ser "Mufino", e o número da posição da lista que eu quero que o programa mostre, será 3.

O grande pega é esse mesmo, eu não sei como dizer qual o número da posição, sem definir antes o nome do item. Definir o nome do item no código para mostrar a sua posição, é o que eu não quero.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer pegar o terceiro item da lista, deve usar colchetes para acessar o item da lista que quer. É importante lembrar que os índices começam em `0`, então pra acessar o 3o item, deve-se buscar pelo índice 2:

```
nome_completo = input('Por favor, informe seu nome completo: ')
lista_nome_completo = nome_completo.split()
print('O elemento 3 da lista é {}'.format(minha_lista[2]))
```

Se quiser pegar o último nome sempre, deve pegar o tamanho da lista. Um atalho pro índice é que `-1` é o índice do último elemento.

```
nome_completo = input('Por favor, informe seu nome completo: ')
lista_nome_completo = nome_completo.split()
ultimo_elemento = len(lista_nome_completo) - 1
print('O último elemento da lista é o de número {}, e é {}'.format(ultimo_elemento, lista_nome_completo[-1]))
```

Comment: Agradeço muito pela resposta, mas infelizmente não é o que quero. Talvez eu não tenha conseguido ser claro o suficiente. 
Vou usar o seu código para tentar esclarecer a situação:
O nome será entrado pelo teclado pelo usuário, ou seja, não é fixo. Dessa maneira, o usuário poderia entrar com 'João Mota Silva Mufino', na próxima compilação. Dessa maneira, o que eu iria querer como saída é:

"O terceiro item da lista é : Mufino
E ele se encontra na posição: 3"

Conseguiu entender que eu quero primeiro selecionar um item na lista pelo número de sua posição, e depois printar a posição?

Comment: @PedroLucas96 acho que talvez tenha entendido; veja a edição da resposta.

Comment: Pedro, meu xará, agora eu tenho certeza que o erro foi meu e na forma com que me expressei. (Sou novo por aqui)

Mas ok, estamos quase lá, vou utilizar o seu código como um exemplo bem direto agora:

Sabendo que para printar o último item da lista, eu usarei esse comando aí, como eu faço agora para mostrar na tela, qual o **número** da posição que ele se encontra? 
Conseguiu entender melhor agora?

Se por acaso na próxima execução do programa, eu digitar o nome 'Carlos Prado Matias Saraiva Junior Feitosa', vou querer mostrar a ultima pos, que será 'Feitosa', e o número dela, 5.

Comment: Amigo, porque você não usa matriz? Ou que tal um dicionário contendo listas? Ou o inverso.

Comment: @PedroLucas96 O segundo exemplo também mostra a posição do último elemento.